# What is a good practice for setting up a redux-backed form in Twilio Flex that keeps state for each reservation?

Tags: twilio-flex

I am building a React form in the CRM pane of Flex which will `POST` data to an external service when the agent fills out the form and hits a submit button.  Using the example code from `create-flex-plugin` from Plugin Builder v3, I have successfully persisted the data from a form field in redux.  However, as an agent in Flex, if I have multiple reservations open, when I toggle between them they use the same data.  How do I design my form so that an agent can enter data in the form for different reservations and they are kept separately?

I am relatively new to Flex, React and Redux, and not sure if there is anything Flex-specific about what I need to do, especially when handling multiple concurrent reservations.  I've thought of keeping a Map keyed by reservationId or taskId in redux, but it's not clear how I'd pass the taskId into the reducer.  I am also not sure if other tools like redux-form will play nice with Flex's design.

Being pointed in the right direction or getting some sample code would be a great help.

My current implementation, which persists a field called 'subcategory', looks like this:

**HrmFormState.js**

```
const UPDATE_FORM = 'UPDATE_FORM';

const initialState = {
  subcategory: 'my category',
};

export class Actions {
  static updateForm = (e) => ({ type: UPDATE_FORM, text: e.target.value });
}

export function reduce(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case UPDATE_FORM: {
      return {
        ...state,
        subcategory: action.text,
      };
    }

    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

**HrmForm.Container.js**

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';

import { Actions } from '../../states/HrmFormState';
import HrmForm from './HrmForm';

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  subcategory: state['hrm-form'].hrmForm.subcategory,
});

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  updateForm: bindActionCreators(Actions.updateForm, dispatch),
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(HrmForm);
```

**HrmForm.jsx (snippet)**

```
  render() {
    if (!this.props.task) {
      return null;
    }

    return (
      <HrmFormComponentStyles>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <label>
            Subcategory:
            <input type="text" value={this.props.subcategory} 
              onChange={this.props.updateForm} />
          </label>
          <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>
      </HrmFormComponentStyles>
    );
  }
```